# How to remove "hao123.com" start page from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I've installed an application that hijacked Chrome's start up page.

I've tried [this procedure](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95421), then I tried a Windows registry search. I can't get rid of of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the hao123 URL was added as a parameter on the shortcut that launches the browser.

If you have the same problem, right-click the browser shortcut, choose *Proprieties*, on the shortcut tab look at the end of the target/destination field contents.

Comment: Well you got it now don't forget to mark it solve, IIRC now you can do that after 72 hrs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **AdwCleaner** (I havent used it for Hao123 though)

AdwCleaner is a program that searches for and deletes Adware, Toolbars, Potentially Unwanted Programs (PUP), and browser Hijackers from your computer.  By using AdwCleaner you can easily remove many of these types of programs for a better user experience on your computer and while browsing the web.

Download & Instructions:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the shortcut from the desktop and copied it from the windows button again.

After trying all possible configurations this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: very strange... i did the things you just mentioned. But the result is still there.

Answer (score -1):

It might be more than just your browser's start page; the virus adds itself to the registry and other places. So, better use these steps for cleaning: https://malwaretips.com/blogs/hao-360-cn-removal/

In short:

> STEP 1: Remove Hao.360.cn redirect with [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)
>
> STEP 2: Remove Hao.360.cn browse hijacker with Junkware Removal Tool
>
> STEP 3: Clean up the various Windows shortcuts that have been hijacked by Hao.360.cn virus
>
> STEP 4: Remove Hao.360.cn virus with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free
>
> STEP 5: Double-check for the “Hao.360.cn” malware with HitmanPro
>
> (Optional) STEP 6: Remove Hao.360.cn from Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/531467)

Comment: Thanks for your explain , otherwise i do this to try to remove the malware, success to delete all the programs but my chrome still open on the chinese page.